# How to access char in TStringGrid?

Tags: string, delphi, datagrid

How to get a char from TStringGrid in Delphi?

```
StringGrid1.Cells[X, Y, Z]//doesn't work
StringGrid1.Cells[X][Y][Z]//doesn't work
```

Comment: `StringGrid1.Cells[X, Y][Z]`

Comment: @TLama: That isn't a comment; it's an answer.

Comment: Hmm... in Russia that would be called cannoneer's fork ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that `StringGrid1.Cells[X, Y]` is a `string` containing the text in cell with coordinates `X, Y`. You also know that if `S` is a `string`, then `S[n]` is the `n`th character of `S`. Combining this knowledge, you realise that

```
StringGrid1.Cells[X, Y][n]
```

is the `n`th character in the cell with coordinates `X, Y`. But beware: while the cell coordinates are 0-based, the character indices are 1-based. Hence, for example, the first character in the top-left cell is

```
StringGrid1.Cells[0, 0][1]
```

if this cell does indeed contain a string of at least one character.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this method, so I think there is a problem with string's first element not being indexed as 0.